# How do you find and remove the Outlook signature from an email handled by an email receiver in C#?

Tags: 2010, email, outlook, incoming-email

I can't see a tag in html or even the .eml file that distinguishes the signature in an email (specifically Outlook emails).

Is there any way to extract the signature from the email in C#?

Comment: Is this in a specific SharePoint context (i.e. incoming email)?  If so, you should reword the question, if not, than StackOverflow is probably a better place to ask this question.  That being said a signature will be nothing more than text (or html, etc) in the body text.  You would need some sort of regex or other pattern type filter to find them (if you know there will be specific wording in a sig, than you may be able to to just look for blocks of text around that).

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Yes it's incoming email in Sharepoint. I've been checking out the emails coming in in .eml format and there doesn't look like there is any defining tag/statement that seperates the text body and the signature. I wonder if the .mht format does...?